# C# Winforms EF6 - multiple update exception handling

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework-6

C# Winforms, SQL Server, Entity Framework 6.

So I have two tables, `Employee` and `BusinessGroup`.  `Employee` is a foreign key in `BusinessGroup`.

As part of my testing, I'm trying to delete two employees and then calling `SaveChanges()`.

Naturally, it throws a `DbUpdateException` which I catch and am attempting to handle.

**Here's my issue:**  The exception seems to get thrown as soon as the first delete (attempt) takes place.  What I'd like to do for my users is list ALL the records that cause a conflict (two in this case).

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a SQL query or are you asking how to display information in a `winforms` control? What have you tried so far?

Comment: No, not asking how to write an SQL query, just pointing out the underlying DB is an SQL Server.

So far, I have tried catching the exception and decoding it, and that works fine.  Problem is, when multiple records are deleted (via my application) and I do a `SaveChanges()`, I only get the very first entry that failed deletion, I was wondering how I can get ALL the entries that did, or will fail deletion.

Comment: Most likely you will have to write a select statement like `select * from BusinessGroup where EmployeeId in (...)` which would return the employees that cannot be deleted. You may also want to consider using soft deletes instead, by adding an `IsDeleted` column.

Answer (score 0):

Is the record you are trying to delete referenced/foreign keyed on another table? You will need to delete first the referenced record to those employees before actually deleting the employee record itself.

For example, **Table A** is the main table, and is referenced in **Table B**. You will not be able to delete a record in **A** unless you delete first those records in **B** referenced by a record in **A**.

So delete **B** records related to **A** record, then delete record in **A**.

Comment: Thanks, but I understand what the problem is, what I'm trying to work out is how I can get all the records that cause conflicts at once.

Comment: you can create a linq expression to check for existing/referenced records from your base table. or you can create a stored procedure to collect the conflicting records you want to get, and call this using linq. hope it helps.